# In OAuth2 authorization grant flow, how to simulate a user clicking "Authorize" from the browser?

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0

So if I'm at the point in the OAuth2 authorization grant flow, where I call an URL such as "http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=2a514a754809f926b2c0fe4bb2f5f29adfa2684331b433f468f8fa4b8dbb20d5&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3001%2Fauth%2Ftodo%2Fcallback" which typically sends a user to page like the below to ask them to "Authorize", is there a way to either skip this step and just get the token OR simulate that the user pressed Authorize by using a GET call of some kind in actual programming code?

Basically I want to avoid a user having to click "Authorize" and just assume they authorized the app.

[image]

Comment: Your problem lacks some definition. Is there a reason you want to skip this step? For testing? Shot in the dark, you could always call the callback url yourself with a dummy token. But does is the token used for something?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

> The authorization server validates the request to ensure that all
> required parameters are present and valid.  If the request is valid,
> the authorization server authenticates the resource owner and obtains
> an authorization decision (**by asking the resource owner or by
> establishing approval via other means**).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1

If you can control the authorization server's behaviour, then you can skip this step. However, this step is to ensure your user knows what is going on and is okay with the client access its resources, so please understand the implications before doing so.

If you can't control the authorization server's behaviour (e.g. you can't change the source code), then the answer is no.

Depending on your use case, the [client credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) might be more suited for your needs.

Comment: If I own both the client and the server, It's correct to have the login form on the client side, and just POST the user credentials to the server with the rest of params? (The authorization_code grant would be suitable because the client is a SPA and I would use PKCE extension).